# StageWebView AS3 - Check if it failed loading website?

Tags: actionscript-3, stagewebview

Can I somehow check if the stageWebView didn't load the webpage? For example if the user doesn't have internet connection, it won't load google.com... Can I then check if it failed loading Google.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  `StageWebView` throws an `ErrorEvent.ERROR` so you can just set up a listener for it:

```
webView.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);  //webView is a StageWebView
function onError(e:ErrorEvent):void 
{
    trace("Page is not available. Try reloading.");
}
```